# Is it possible to change the color of the Remote Desktop Connection client bar?

Tags: remote-desktop

Sometimes I need to make a Remote Desktop Connection within another connection. This results in two client bars like this:

[image]

As I'm often switching between all three environments, it would be nice if I can change this color of one or both of the bars as it would help me identify the environment I want to minimise. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navigating nested RDP sessions](https://superuser.com/questions/76072/navigating-nested-rdp-sessions)

Comment: Not natively I assume, other similar programs has different toolbars

Comment: The movable bars help the situation, but being able to choose different colors would help a lot more.